# How to time UIImpactFeedbackGenerator with a UIView Key Frame Animation?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, animation

I'm trying to add impact feedback to a custom view controller presentation. The animation is implemented in key frames, and has a bounce at the end so I can't perform the impact in `presentationTransitionDidEnd`. My key frames look something like:

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        // View controller hits its full size; I'd like feedback at the end of this
    }
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        // Expand for bounce
    }
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.75, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        // Back to normal size
    }
}, completion: { ... })
```

Is there a way to run a block of code at a specific point in a key frame animation? Placing it right inside the block doesn't work.